# Retrieve each different InputStream composing a SequenceInputStream

Tags: java, file, stream, inputstream

I'm trying to stream files, with Java, from a Sybase database to the presentation layer of my application, when a client clicks on the download button.

Streaming the files from the database is ok.
But I would like to pass all that different `InputStream` from my DAO to my Controller in one shot.

I saw that we can use `SequenceInputStream` for concatenating multiple `InputStream` (using an `Enumeration`).
The problem is that I do want to process each `InpuStream` composing the `SequenceInputStream` individually (for concatenating them into only one PDF file).

I also tried a `List<InputStream>`, but I've got Serialization problems.

Is there an easy way (or a best way) for doing that ?

Comment: `List<InputStream>` **is** the right solution. You can then process each stream sequentially or even concurrently. Can you show what kind of *Serialization problems* you had?

Comment: Yes I'll copy/paste the log tomorrow if the list is the best way for accessing each `InputStream`.